# Removing VisualBasic runtime from vbproj files

Tags: vb.net

I need to remove VB runtime reference from vbproj files and replace them with C# methods. Can someone explain what the difference between this:

```xml
<Import Include="Microsoft.VisualBasic" />
```

and this:

```xml
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" />
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have vb files and I need to replace vb function (like iif) with C# calls.

Comment: Same project cannot run both vb.net and c#, if your project is a vb.net-project then you have to use vb.net. Or create a new c#-project and convert the code to c#.